Parallel between Cain and Hevel's rivalry with that of Yaakov and Esav's: Could it be that Yaakov and Esav were reincarnations of Hevel and Cain?
It could be said that the rivalry between Cain and Hevel is essentially predicated on the fact that there is a right/proper way to serve G-d. Likewise, part of what led to the rivalry between Yaakov and Esav is the fact that Esav did not really care to serve G-d correctly, if at all, while Yaakov did. And when G-d chose both Hevel and Yaakov over their brothers, their brothers went after them to kill them. Could it be that due to this parallel, Yaakov and Esav were reincarnations of Hevel and Cain?

Kayin wasn't evil. He sought to have a relationship with Hashem, albeit not in a good way. He did teshuva for his sin of killing Hevel. Eisav, on the other hand, was evil through and through. He committed the three Cardinal Sins in a single day. He never repented. His descendants represent the antithesis of the Jews. I don't see a parallel because Yaakov/Eisav and Kayin/Hevel just because they were both siblings.

@Yehuda I'm not saying that the parallel lies in the fact that they're siblings but because both siblings were vying to merit G-d's favor, and one just did it better than the other because they actually did what was right and pleasing before G-d.

Where do you find Eisav vying to merit Hashem's favor?

@Yehuda Instances like him killing Nimrod, honoring his parents, making criminals confess to their wrongdoings (Bereshis Rabbah 63:10) surely indicate that he wanted to merit Hashem's favor. Also, you can just tell from how he reacted to not getting the blessing that he wanted to have G-d's favor.

His killing of Nimrod was self-serving, as was his desire for the brachah. The way he gave up the bechorah in the first place indicates it was not out of a desire for Hashem's favor that he wanted the brachah, but rather out of a desire for the material guarantees contained therein. His honoring of his father was his one redeeming attributes, but the fact that he wanted his father to die so that he could kill Yaakov, again, belies the suggestion that it was l'sheim shomayim.
